# How does the make work when the file is not in target?

Tags: makefile

I was looking a the code of libavcodec. The Makefile of https://github.com/libav/libav/tree/master/libavcodec#. For instance, if you execute make api-example.c, it does recognize it. While there is no target for api-example.c. Moreover, when i remove the Makefile from this directory, it does recognize the target. I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make has a number of built-in rules.  If the file you asked make to build already exists, and there is no target for that file defined that gives any prerequisite make can check to see if it's up to date, then the file is up-to-date by definition: it exists, and has no prerequisites.

The only way a target that has no prerequisites can be out of date is if it doesn't exist: then it has to be created.